# How to make accordion should open from top to bottom?

Tags: accordion

Hi i have used an accordion method but in this it opens the div element from top left to bottom right. i don't want like that i want this one to open from top to bottom.. help me out this please??????? Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#accordion .head').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
</script>

<div id="accordion">
    <h3 class="head"><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div style="background:#f00;">
        <p>First content</p>
        <p>second content</p>
        <p>third content</p>
        <p>fourth content</p>
        <p>fifth content</p>
        <p>six content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This really belongs over at Stack Overflow. It's not a user experience question.

Comment: try: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: And specifically here: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-animate

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery code and edit what u want

```
(function($) {

var allPanels = $('.accordion .dd').hide();

$('.accordion .dt  a').click(function() {
allPanels.slideUp();
$(this).parent().next().slideDown();
return false;
});
})(jQuery)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X9sz8/